# How to restrict if the last field of a Vertical field maneger has focus in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have one VerticalFieldManager with 24 editfield and labelfields.

I want to restrict the scroll: while the first Editfield has focus the scroll should not go upwards and while the last Editfield has focus the scroll should not go downwards.

Answer (score 0):

Create VerticalFieldManager as below.

```
 VerticalFieldManager vfm  = new VerticalFieldManager    (VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
```